# Restricting user interaction in UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I want to restrict the users from using the links in a UIWebView. Hence, showing only single a HTML page with no navigation.

I know I can do that using the "User Interaction" option of UIWebView but I can't use that since it disables scrolling as well, and the user cannot view the complete page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind them seeing the links, you could use a [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) to detect when a page begins loading and cancel it.

If you don't want them to see the links at all, you could modify the HTML before rendering it.  Using libxml is pretty [easy](http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/03/11/adding-the-libxml-framework-to-your-iphone-app/)'s and it's htmlparser.h can probably do what you need.  If you don't like that, [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) works well too.

Answer (score 7):

My situation demanded that a user really can ONLY look at the page, but not interact at all (specifically with respect to copying content--it was a security issue).  Here's what I did:

```
for (UIView *thisView in webView.scrollView.subviews)
{
    thisView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the WKWebView in a UIView and then set `webViewWrapper.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

to disable navigation with links

```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.stopLoading()
    
}
```