# WKWebview: Disable interaction and clicks on links

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

Is there a way to disable interactions on a webview?
So that the user can not go any further than the webview that is loaded?

EDIT:
Disabling UserInteractions is not a solution because the website still has to be scrollable.

Comment: you can implement delegate methods of webview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting user interaction in UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452961/restricting-user-interaction-in-uiwebview)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface ViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate>
```

Set your `WKWebView`'s `navigationDelegate` property:

```
self.wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

Then implement the policy for the URL(s) that you want to restrict:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@"somedomain.com/url/here"]) {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
    else {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is when i got a url like google.com i.e and it should not open google.com/"something" it does not work with containsString but i can not diasable userInteractions because of scrolling.

Comment: You can use isEqualToString or some other comparison in that case.

Answer (score 9):

The `WKNavigationDelegate` solution only prevents the user from following links. I also have form controls that I want to prevent interaction with, while still allowing the page to be scrolled. Eventually I figured out that this could be achieved by disabling the subviews of the web view's scroll view:

**Swift**

```
self.webView.scrollView.subviews.forEach { $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = false }
```

**Objective-C**

```
for (UIView *subview in self.webView.scrollView.subviews)
{
    subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: VinneyCoyne's answer still allows the display of menu.. but prevents interaction with it. But this answer is perfect. No interaction except scrolling of the webview, which is what i want. Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing this error `Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'scrollView'`

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia That's odd, it's a publicly accessible field of that class (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1614784-scrollview). I assume you haven't inadvertently defined another type called `WKWebView`? Maybe it's some Xcode problem that can be fixed with a restart?

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to give the delegate to your webkit then add below code.
Swift 5.0

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    Activity.stopAnimating()
    let javascriptStyle = "var css = '*{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none}'; var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var style = document.createElement('style'); style.type = 'text/css'; style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); head.appendChild(style);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptStyle, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

What this code will do, we add programmatically css that will disable interaction in webview

Answer (score 1):

These javascript lines will disable long presses and link touches by overriding the HTML. Frame based things like embedded youtube videos will still work.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none'")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { elems[i]['href'] = 'javascript:(void)'; }")
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do it as follow.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - UIWebView Methods

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {



    return YES;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
//disable user interaction 
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
//enable user interaction
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //enable user interaction
}
```